# Filter outlook emails until a threshold/count is reached

Tags: email, count, outlook, threshold

I get a set of alerts by email from a device anytime it has connectivity issues. It is typical to see about 15 email alerts every day for connectivity issues for several reasons. These are mostly ignored.

However, when there is a connectivity issue that is severely affecting other systems, we get a lot more emails over the period the connectivity issue lasts for. Unfortunately, I can’t get my developers to fix or threshold this from the source.

My question is: how do I create an outlook rule or script to move all incoming emails from a particular sender containing a particular string in the body to the deleted items folder if 15 or less emails are received, but stop filtering as soon as 16 or more are received on any given day?

Answer (score 0):

While you can run a VBA macro/script with a Rule, it's almost always best to implement message delivery processing manually without relying on Rules which could fail or don't support the criteria you need (like in this case).

So I would monitor the [Application.NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686.aspx) event to begin inspecting every received message, and implement counters accordingly to stop processing when required.